# Connman network configuration for default interface

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ethernet, beagleboneblack

I have a BeagleBone Green board running Debian. It uses Connman as the network manager.

The configuration file should be /etc/connman/main.conf however this doesn't exist.

I have two active network interfaces connecting to the internet, a wi-fi interface wlan0, and ethernet interface eth0.

Which interface takes preference / priority in this case when communicating to the outside world? Where is this configured if there is no /etc/connman/main.conf.

Answer (score 3):

> Which interface takes preference / priority in this case when communicating to the outside world?

Priority should be set in the [`main.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/connman/connman.conf.5.en.html), you can create it manually.

Answer from Arch-linux wiki:

> [Prefer ethernet to wireless](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ConnMan#Prefer_ethernet_to_wireless)
>
> By default ConnMan does not prefer ethernet over wireless, which can lead to it deciding to stick with a slow wireless network even when ethernet is available. You can tell connman to prefer ethernet adding the following to `/etc/connman/main.conf`:

```
[General]
PreferredTechnologies=ethernet,wifi
```